# Reading very long lines from a .txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got the following .txt file that I uploaded on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2g51y1nxe4b5ba/sample.txt?dl=0), I want to read it line by line and do some processing on each line, however as I try to read each line, I don't get the output I expect. Each line in the txt file is too long and I think that's the reason for the problem.

How can I resolve this problem, any suggestions or solutions to get each line properly is welcome. Here is the code I use:

```
import sys
import fileinput

def readline():
    for line in fileinput.input("sample.txt"):
        print line


def main():
    readline()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried many variations of reading from the .txt file with no luck. Here is [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ih5qhkau204ajyg/output.txt?dl=0) from Sample.txt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long is the line? What makes you think it's too long?

Comment: You have to define how you want your line to be separated into different lines. For eg: In English language a full stop `.` defines an end of a line in general. Similarly you have to decide what symbol in your file will determine the end of a line. Please post a small example of your desired output!

Comment: I think it is very long because the first line for instance is 309046 characters including spaces.

Comment: Desired output is exactly same as the sample file, no symbol will define end of a line, a line in the output will end exactly where a corresponding line ends in the sample file. The file should be read and printed out on the shell.

Comment: After properly looking at the *raw* sample file (and not the htmlified version from dropbox): It looks like the format is `[tag]['logline1', 'logline2', ...]\n`. If you want that separate, you need to parse it. Or tell the generator of that file not to generate it in this way ;-).

Comment: Thanks, you are right but how can I parse it, using regex of some kind?